# How to set Streaming Video Format from webcam using libvlc api.?

Tags: webcam, live-streaming, mjpeg, libvlc

I am developing an application in which I am supposed to get Streaming using webcam,
For this I have used the libvlc api,
I am able to stream from webcam,
But I am getting the stream in the YUYV format,
but I want the streaming in the MJPEG format,
so can anybody help me how to set streaming format in libvlc.?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the parameter "sout" to libvlc_vlm_add_broadcast function. In it, you can specify the desired format.
For instance:

```
const char *sout = "#transcode{vcodec=mjpg, vb=1600}:http{dst=127.0.0.1:8090/cam.mp4}";
libvlc_vlm_add_broadcast(mVLCInst, media_name, "dshow://", sout, 0, NULL, true, false);
```

dshow:// is used on Windows, for Linux you use v4l2:///dev/videoX, where X is the cam ID.